# Show that any continuous function on $[0,1]$ such that $(f(x))^n =0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ , then $f = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Question : Let $C[0,1]$ be the ring of all real valued continuous function on $[0,1]$. Show that if $f \in C([0,1])$ is such that  $f((x))^n  = 0 $ $\forall x \in [0,1]$, for some $n >1$, then $f(x) = 0$ $\forall x \in [0,1]$.

Please give me idea how to solve. Any help would be appreciated . Thank you

Comment: Was is $f((x))^n$?

Comment: Should there be an "for a given $n$" somewhere? (in particular, is it quantified before or after the $x$?)

Comment: $(f(x))^n$ means that $f(x) \times f(x) \times \cdots \times f(x)$ n times

Comment: No, please read more carefully your homework: $f(x)^n$ is a bad notation for the $n$th derivative of $f$ at $x$.

Comment: @Did Strictly speaking, OP might know what his/her notation means, and is simply pointing out to me an irrelevant fact that appears nowhere in his/her question (note the parens).

Comment: @treble Strictly speaking, I am not sure what you are trying to say. Regarding the statement of the question, let us wait and see, shall we?

Comment: @Did $f((x))^n$ is not the same symbol as $(f(x))^n$ :P Either way I don't know what's going on.

Comment: @ Did: I have read carefully, this is not $n-th$ derivative , this means that n times multiplication of $f(x)$

Comment: @user120386 Wow. Stunned I am. What is your source?

Comment: As it is, the problem seems absurdly trivial. Since for all $x$, the $n$-th power of $f(x)$ is $0$, then $f(x)=0$ for all $x$. So $f=0$.

Comment: @Did : You can see  question 81 in the link http://csirhrdg.res.in/mathCEN_June2015.pdf

Comment: OK, thanks, then see @G.Sassatelli's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $\Bbb R$ is a field, and hence an integral domain, so the only zero divisor in $\Bbb R$ is zero itself.

Comment: I'm still not sure if you've answered the question of when $n$ is quantified. It turns out it doesn't matter if you use this technique, but it's mildly more interesting if it's $\forall x\exists n$ rather than the other way around.

Comment: Eric : your answer is fine and thanks